# XMLRPC in android error extra parameter

Tags: android, xml-rpc

I have problem with XMLRPC when I pass parameter to invoke server.

```
    JSONObject s_profile = new JSONObject();
    s_profile.put("token", tokenId);
    s_profile.put("lname", Fname.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("lname", Lname.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("address", address.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("city", city.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("state", state.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("homePhone", homephone.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("cellphone", cellphone.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("zipcode", zipcode.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("contactname", contact.getText().toString());
    s_profile.put("contactphone", phone.getText().toString());
    XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(Config.urlApi);
    try {

         obj = (HashMap<String, String>) client.call("requestUpdatePatientProfile",s_profile.toString());

    } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get error is "org.xmlrpc.android.xmlrpcfault: xmlrpc fault: object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Must I to do?

Answer (score 0):

cross check your XMLRPC Connection is not null

```
 //..
 XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(Config.urlApi);

 if(client != null){

   //your code here
 }
```